# How to generate PDF in laravel using laravel-dompdf library

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I'm trying to generate pdf using laravel-dompdf library. I had downloaded the package through composer.

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

I had updated my config >> app.php

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
    ....
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
],
```

I included PDF class in my controller

```
use PDF;
```

My controller **HomeController.php** is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use PDF;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('welcome');
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
    }
}
```

But when I call this method it shows the following error

> "fopen(C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Laravel\PDFGenerator\storage\fonts/\b4947bfc07f9f11b363f4d7446cd3e99.ufm):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

I had also added the following to my bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('dompdf');
```

There is no dompdf.php is generated in my config directory. I had tried

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"
```

But it shows the following error

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in

> C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Laravel\PDFGenerator\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:767
>   Stack trace:
>   C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Laravel\PDFGenerator\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(767):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
>   C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Laravel\PDFGenerator\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(646):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
>   C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Laravel\PDFGenerator\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(601):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array)
>   C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Laravel\PDFGenerator\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(740):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
>   C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Laravel\PDFGenerator\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1210):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config') C:\U in
>   C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Laravel\PDFGenerator\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 767

Comment: what about Configuration ?

Comment: There is no dompdf.php file generated in config directory

Comment: I had updated my question with more detail

Comment: I solved this problem. [here my answer with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474036/barryvdh-laravel-dompdf-fopen-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/55015148#55015148):

Comment: I think this tutorial is helpfull: [How to create dompdf in laravel](https://devnote.in/laravel-7-pdf-generator-tutorial-using-dompdf/)

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('dompdf');
```

It is for Lumen not Laravel.
You still need to specify font.
Here is my way:

```
$pdf = PDF::setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'dejavu serif'])->loadView('some_view', $data);
return $pdf->stream('filename.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

The defaults configuration settings are set in config/dompdf.php. Copy this file to your own config directory to modify the values. You can publish the config using this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

You can still alter the dompdf options in your code before generating the pdf using this command:

```
PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
```

Available options and their defaults:

```
rootDir: "{app_directory}/vendor/dompdf/dompdf"
tempDir: "/tmp" (available in config/dompdf.php)
fontDir: "{app_directory}/storage/fonts/" (available in config/dompdf.php)
fontCache: "{app_directory}/storage/fonts/" (available in config/dompdf.php)
chroot: "{app_directory}" (available in config/dompdf.php)
logOutputFile: "/tmp/log.htm"
defaultMediaType: "screen" (available in config/dompdf.php)
defaultPaperSize: "a4" (available in config/dompdf.php)
defaultFont: "serif" (available in config/dompdf.php)
dpi: 96 (available in config/dompdf.php)
fontHeightRatio: 1.1 (available in config/dompdf.php)
isPhpEnabled: false (available in config/dompdf.php)
isRemoteEnabled: true (available in config/dompdf.php)
isJavascriptEnabled: true (available in config/dompdf.php)
isHtml5ParserEnabled: false (available in config/dompdf.php)
isFontSubsettingEnabled: false (available in config/dompdf.php)
debugPng: false
debugKeepTemp: false
debugCss: false
debugLayout: false
debugLayoutLines: true
debugLayoutBlocks: true
debugLayoutInline: true
debugLayoutPaddingBox: true
pdfBackend: "CPDF" (available in config/dompdf.php)
pdflibLicense: ""
adminUsername: "user"
adminPassword: "password"
```

Comment: I'm not able to publish using >>  php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"

Comment: what is your laravel version?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Laravel\PDFGenerator\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:767